# Navigation Bar of Table View is going down

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, storyboard

I tried to add navigation bar to table view in Main.storyboard.
In Main.storyboard, there is no problem navigation bar is seen in the **up** part of table view.

Also, no problem before data is loaded. Navigation bar is seen in the **up** part of table view.

[image: Image 1]

But, when all data is loaded, navigation bar is going to **down**.

[image: Image 2]

I want to keep navigation bar in above part of tableview. 
Where am I wrong? How to solve this problem?

I think, FirstViewController.swift is not important, nevertheless I am sharing all code.

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit


class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var tbCount = 0

    var myMp3s = [Mp3]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        let url = URL(string: "http://example.php")


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                let posts = json["server_response"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? []


                for i in posts {

                    print(i["id"]!)

                    let mp3 = Mp3(id: i["id"] as! String, category: i["kategori"] as! String)

                    self.myMp3s.append(mp3)


                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()


                print("counte", self.myMp3s.count)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }).resume()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myMp3s.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell  = UITableViewCell()

        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.myMp3s[indexPath.row].category

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(myMp3s[indexPath.row].category)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Comment: try to disable **translucent** property  of NavigationController's navigationBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Try this]

This will create a navigation bar

Comment: I did what you say but title is null, How to set Title? 
I am newbie

https://i.hizliresim.com/Ak22dL.png

Comment: you can click on the navigation bar in the storyboard and then set the title.

Comment: or you can say in code: self.title = "title" @gurkanstack

Comment: Good job! @gurkanstack

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you have drag and drop the `NavigationBar` from `Object library` to your `ViewController` so remove it. If you want to show the `NavigationBar` embed `YourViewController` to `UINavigtionController`.

To `Embed` your `ViewController` to `NavigationConttoller` follow this steps.

1. Select your `ViewController` in Interface builder
2. Go to the `Editor` menu and select the Embed In.
3. From the new option list select `NavigationController`

To set `title` to your `Navigation bar`, select the `Navigation Item` for your ViewController from the `Document Outline Bar` after that go in `Attribute Inspector` section and set title.

You can also set title programmatically, add below line in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.title = "Title"
```

[image]

Comment: I did what you say but title is null, How to set Title? I am newbie https://i.hizliresim.com/Ak22dL.png

Comment: @gurkanstack Welcome mate, Glad it works for you, Also remember to never add NavigationBar like you have done today don't drag and drop it

Comment: Okey, I wil not forget your advices :)

Answer (score 0):

As Per My View Try To set A Navigationbar In a headerview of tableview. that will not move down.